# Requesting an API call that requires an oauth token in python

Tags: python, json, oauth, python-requests, python-requests-html

So i'm writing a program that post's data to a url and get's the response. In postman it requires a token. So when I tried to make it in python it's giving me a response [401].

The problem I have is trying to get the token first and then passing it to my post_data method.

I'm going to put *** by the URL and username and password for privacy concerns.

```
import requests
import json
import pprint
import urllib

def get_token():
    tokenurl='***'
    data={
            'grant_type':'password',
            'username':'***',
            'password':'***'
            }
    token=requests.post(tokenurl,data=data)
    print(token)    
get_token()

def post_data():
    url1='***'
    data={"***"
      }

    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(url, data=data_json, headers=headers)
    pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Comment: You should use one of the recommended authentication methods described in the [requests docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#authentication)

Comment: `post_data()` doesn't appear to call `get_token()`, so how does it get the token?

Comment: True so I've fixed my get token method. Now i'm getting the token in the json format. I need to parse it and load it into the post_data method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post_data() function, you can add your generated token to the headers

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'token ***'}
```

*** is your generated token

Comment: So I'm getting response[200] in my get_token method. It's not printing the token.

Comment: can you try print (token.text)

Comment: So it's giving me the token with other information in a json format. I just need to parse it and take the token out.